# what CSS properties should I add to make the scroll appear in this table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, scroll

I have the following table:
['table'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHfBF.png)
how cam I save it's width Even when the screen is narrowed and only add a scroll to show it, I have added `overflow: scroll;` to the container `<div>` but it looks like this:
['table'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5QSA.png)

what CSS properties should I add to make the scroll appear in this table to make it responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'overflow-x: auto;' to container:

```
<div class"table-responsive" style="overflow-x: auto;">
  <table style="width:200vw;">
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```